# Convert a Dictionary<string,string> to an array

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I want to convert a Dictionary to an array in C#. The array should be in the following format:

```
string[] array = {"key1=value1","key2=value2","key1=value1"}
```

How to do this effectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string[] array = dictionary
                .Select(kvp => string.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

LINQ makes that really easy:

```
string[] array = dictionary.Select(pair => string.Format("{0}={1}",
                                                         pair.Key, pair.Value))
                           .ToArray();
```

This takes advantage of the fact that [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`:

- The [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method loops over each pair in the dictionary, applying the given delegate to each pair
- Our delegate (specified with a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)) converts a pair to a string using `string.Format`
- The [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) call converts a sequence into an array

If this is the first time you've seen LINQ, I *strongly* recommend that you look at it more. It's an amazing way of dealing with data.

In C# 6, the `string.Format` code can be replaced with interpolated string literals, making it rather more compact:

```
string[] array = dictionary.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key}={pair.Value}")
                           .ToArray();
```